# OpenVpn dows not showing in GUI

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

I have installed OpenVpn using

```
sudo apt-get install openvpn
```

it works for command line nut in Network Connection i can not see any OpenVpn option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you also need to install GUI Tools

you can install them via

```
sudo apt-get install openvpn network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome
```